# Are there references to WWE Superstars in Real Steel?

Tags: real-steel, wwe

In the movie Real Steel,

- Atom is called the People's Champ, which seems like a direct reference to The Rock.
- In the final fight against Zeus, after Atom is down, he got up just like Undertaker does. The Undertaker [does](http://youtu.be/YkcxEo2kQlA) the exact same thing after getting beaten up pretty badly.
- Zeus' entrance is just like Triple H's.(The trademark fist up and evil green color theme)

Is this some sort of homage/tribute? Or stolen just cuz they are cool? Or am I just imagining things

Comment: The movie was based on boxing rather than free-style fighting, so I don't think there're any connections, though I'd appreciate that you've noticed those facts.

Comment: The People's Champ was likely a reference to boxing legend Muhammad Ali.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think so....the fighting between the 'bots in the movie is mainly boxing-oriented. Some of the moves may look similar, but I don't see a People's Elbow or a Pedigree happening in the movie, so I doubt it.

I think these parts of the movie are just symbolic. Atom's the People's Champ because he represents a more human way of fighting, which is more relatable than Zeus, who is "fully automatic".

It just boils down to the themes, I think...

EDIT: I noticed you said that both Atom and Zeus do the "sit-up", and I forgot that they do both do that. I guess that's more of the fact that their both robots.

Comment: I should've worded my question more appropriately. I should've used the word `subtle` somewhere cuz that's what I intended to say. There is no need for a people's elbow or a pedigree for associating  with WWE. And I am not saying that there is no reason for each of their behaviors. About the undertaker(a minor correction), only Atom does that situp not Zeus. I like the Zeus- fully automatic and Atom, more human bit of your answer

Comment: okay. At the same time, however, Zeus does do that push-up move when he is downed, which is just as robotic. Guess that just proves that they are both robots...

Answer (score 1):

searching key words "wwe real steel" brought me here.  i was curious about the exact same thing, but the reference that really got me marking out was the reference to where Atom hails from, and it was cited as "parts unknown", which is exactly how The Ultimate Warrior and Kane (half-brother of The Undertaker) are billed in the WWE.  Chris Jericho, at one point, even referenced it and said he's terrified of wrestlers who hail from "Parts Unknown."

Also, I'm pretty convinced that taking elements from prowrestling/WWE was intentional.  I want to make it clear that I'm completely aware that the movie is about robot that uses a "boxing" style of fighting, but the element of gimmicks (dancing robot), baby face/heel competitors (Atom is cheered, Zeus is booed), the use of a femme fatale authority figure/valet, the father (money)/daughter(brains)/fighter(brawn) combo as dictating the shots in the league is like a reference to vince/stephanie/hhh management.

I think the technical parts are expressly based on wrestling, but the "drama", "entertainment" and "exhibition"/"showmanship" elements are all implicitly prowrestling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaken and just imagining things. Real Steel is based on the short story “Steel” by [Richard Matheson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Matheson) (1956). The story takes place in the not so distant future.
Though Atom is not a physical or “real” character and had no speaking lines, there was something definitely human about him and the bots would knocking out all the WWE Superstars. 
I think they'd definitely paid tribute to Richard Matheson rather than WWE Superstars. According to me, the atoms had its **unique traits of boxing style** rather than wrestling style.

Comment: You haven't given any concrete reason for your statement, but I do appreciate the reference to Richard Matheson.

Comment: @LelouchLamperouge, The bots has its unique boxing style.So don't confuse it with wrestling style.